# AES 256 with PKCS7 padding

Tags: php, openssl, aes, padding, mcrypt

> The GST Council has approved the implementation of ‘e-Invoicing’ or ‘electronic invoicing’ of Business to Business (B2B) invoices to GST System if company turnover is greater that 500 crore. Ref of gst portal API :[einv-apisandbox.nic.in/index.html](http://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/)

I have to decrypt the encrypted SEK using APP key  and encode json data using decrypted SEK to post for Einvoice Generation and i found sample code for java and C# and i have converted in PHP but unfortunately failed to get desired output

In my case encrypted SEK is:    `oRvKfBtmgNTSuk/oXUhiLOjXi45jiWA2oKNxhhQM3UH2o/32YWGLbUjK1/dohPe3`

APP key: `fao1PoKaLgd11xMrWTiL2cggAfx9QMwM`

Symmetric decryption (AES) (in java)

```
public static String decrptyBySyymetricKey(String encryptedSek, byte[] appKey)
{
    Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(appKey, "AES"); // converts bytes(32 byte random generated) to key
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // encryption type = AES with padding PKCS5
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey); // initiate decryption type with the key
        byte[] encryptedSekBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedSek); // decode the base64 encryptedSek to bytes
        byte[] decryptedSekBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedSekBytes); // decrypt the encryptedSek with the initialized cipher containing the key(Results in bytes)
        String decryptedSek = Base64.encodeBase64String(decryptedSekBytes); // convert the decryptedSek(bytes) to Base64 StriNG
        return decryptedSek; // return results in base64 string
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return "Exception; "+e;
    }
}
```

Symmetric encryption (AES) (in java)

```
public static string EncryptBySymmetricKey(string text, string sek)
    {
    //Encrypting SEK
    try
    {
      byte[] dataToEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
      var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sek);
      AesManaged tdes = new AesManaged();
      tdes.KeySize = 256;
      tdes.BlockSize = 128;
      tdes.Key = keyBytes;
      tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
      tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      pICryptoTransform encrypt__1 = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
      byte[] deCipher = encrypt__1.TransformFinalBlock(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
      tdes.Clear();
      string EK_result = Convert.ToBase64String(deCipher);
      return EK_result;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw ex;
   }
 }
```

Symmetric encryption (AES) (in PHP)

```
function encrypt($data, $key)
{
    $padding = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash('SHA256', $key, true), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
 }
```

Symmetric decryption (AES) (in PHP)

```
function decrypt($key, $str) 
{
    $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hash('SHA256', $key, true), $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);
    $len = strlen($str);
    $pad = ord($str[$len-1]);
    
    return base64_encode( substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad));
}
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2):

The decryption of the session key (SEK) with the AppKey is possible in PHP as follows:

```php
function decrptyBySymmetricKey($encSekB64, $appKey) {
    $sek = openssl_decrypt($encSekB64, "aes-256-ecb", $appKey, 0);                  // the SEK
    $sekB64 = base64_encode($sek);                                                  // the Base64 encoded SEK
    return $sekB64;
}
```

The encryption of data with the SEK is possible in PHP as follows:

```php
function encryptBySymmetricKey($dataB64, $sekB64){
    $data = base64_decode($dataB64);                                                // the data to encrypt
    $sek = base64_decode($sekB64);                                                  // the SEK
    $encDataB64 = openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-ecb", $sek, 0);                   // the Base64 encoded ciphertext
    return $encDataB64;
}
```

Both functions can be tested with the following data:

```php
$appKey = 'fao1PoKaLgd11xMrWTiL2cggAfx9QMwM';                                       // the 32 bytes AppKey
$encSekB64 = 'oRvKfBtmgNTSuk/oXUhiLOjXi45jiWA2oKNxhhQM3UH2o/32YWGLbUjK1/dohPe3';    // the Base64 encoded encrypted SEK 
$dataB64 = 'VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZw==';          // the base64 encoded data
$sekB64 = decrptyBySymmetricKey($encSekB64, $appKey);                               // the Base64 encoded SEK   
$encDataB64 = encryptBySymmetricKey($dataB64, $sekB64);                             // the Base64 encoded ciphertext
echo $sekB64 . "\n";                                                                // zVoede7m2nnvMHcWYIfKhrvsilSFEZYiltJmxVQQnAQ=
echo $encDataB64;                                                                   // JS+hxYf64FMHThrhoIejqk3VjGwFw+GTYzUyVKc6GEOLKERVuvaNY91zPdo829r0
```

The Java method `decryptBySymmetricKey` returns with

```java
byte[] appKey = "fao1PoKaLgd11xMrWTiL2cggAfx9QMwM".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String encSekB64 = "oRvKfBtmgNTSuk/oXUhiLOjXi45jiWA2oKNxhhQM3UH2o/32YWGLbUjK1/dohPe3";
String sekB64 = decryptBySymmetricKey(encSekB64, appKey);
```

the same value for the Base64 encoded SEK (`zVoede7m2nnvMHcWYIfKhrvsilSFEZYiltJmxVQQnAQ=`).

Likewise, the C# method `EncryptBySymmetricKey` (erroneously labeled in the question as Java function) returns with

```c#
string dataB64 = "VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZw==";
string sekB64 = "zVoede7m2nnvMHcWYIfKhrvsilSFEZYiltJmxVQQnAQ=";
string encDataB64 = EncryptBySymmetricKey(dataB64, sekB64);
```

the same value for the Base64 encoded ciphertext (`JS+hxYf64FMHThrhoIejqk3VjGwFw+GTYzUyVKc6GEOLKERVuvaNY91zPdo829r0`).

Note:

- The deprecated *mcrypt* is not used. Instead *openssl* is applied.
- Besides the security aspect, *openssl* has the advantage over *mcrypt*, that PKCS7 padding is implicitly used, analogous to the C#/Java code. *mcrypt* applies Zero padding, so a user defined padding was necessary, which is obsolete with *openssl*.
- The key is not derived from the passed key via SHA256, but applied directly, analogous to the C#/Java code.

Comment: Required More help:  Where you have applied PaddingMode.PKCS7

Comment: @Ashishgupta - As mentioned in the notes above, `openssl_encrypt()` and `openssl_decrypt()` use PKCS7 padding _by default_, i.e. it is _not explicitly_ specified (otherwise the result of the Java/C# code would not be reproduced either).

Comment: Thanks for your help. unfortunately my problem not resolved. When i posting encDataB64 data then getting error from API " "ErrorMessage": "Application Error, Please Contact the help desk"   but when i encode my json fdirectly from sandbox portal ithen Einvoice successfully generated and Getting IRN code. now  i am unable to find the issue where i am doing wrong.   Sandbox portal given the public key and certificate box (this is for your reference)

Answer (score 0):

You also might need to try with postman tool. I achieve the same and able to connect the NIC system but as per the document they have provided it's not possible to achieve the same encryption using OpenSSL or other encryption tool.

Now I moved on to GSP based API connectivity solution you might check this stuff from

https://github.com/sujianalytics/gst-e-invoicing-sap

It's open source but not relevant for your issue, might need to upgrade little bit as per your requirement.